# AWS Data Pipeline - SQLActivity into S3 (MySQL DB)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

### What have I tried

[image]

As you can see here, this is my configuration on trying to save the output data from query to s3 as CSV. The query was successful (from what I've check on the logs) but it seems that it doesn't create any file on the s3 output location.

### Main Problem

I know about the CopyActivity and I tried that successfully, but the problem is that my query is too long that it reaches the limit 10240. From what I've searched, you can save the SQL file on S3 then use SQL Activity to add Script URI and point it on the SQL file saved on S3. But it seems that only CopyActivity can create and save CSV as an output on S3.

### Questions

- Is there any work around on long query to still use Copy Activity?
- Is there a way to use the SQL Activity and create CSV file on S3?
- Is it breaking down the SQL query will be the only solution?